# Ошибка: method PrintStream.println() is not applicable

Tags: java

```
class Main {
  public static int namadd(int a , int b) {
    return a+b;
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a=73,b=62;
    System.out.println("a + b = %d + %d = %d",a,b,namadd(a,b));
  }
}
```

Пожалуйста объясните ошибку и напишите как будет правильно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**В Java есть 3 метода для вывода информации в консоль.**

```java
System.out.print();
System.out.println();
System.out.printf();
```

В чём их отличия? На самом деле, между `System.out.print()` и `System.out.println()` их фактически только одно: второй после вывода строки переводит курсор на новую строку, то есть

---

```java
System.out.print("Hello");
System.out.print("Java");
```

Вывод:

```
HelloJava
```

---

```java
System.out.print("Hello");
System.out.println("Java");
```

Вывод:

```
Hello
Java
```

---

Теперь, ответ на ваш вопрос. Вы скорее всего хотите использовать форматированный вывод. Для этого применяется метод `System.out.printf()`, где сначала передаётся строка с модификаторами, а дальше аргументы которые будут подстанавливаться на место модификаторов. Я вижу решение в

```java
class Main {
  public static int namadd(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a = 73, b = 62;
    System.out.printf("a + b = %d + %d = %d", a, b, namadd(a,b));
  }
}
```

О модификаторах можно почитать [тут](https://metanit.com/java/tutorial/2.9.php).

Answer (score 0):

Для форматированного вывода используйте printf() вместо println()

```
System.out.printf(string);
System.out.printf(format, arguments);
System.out.printf(locale, format, arguments);
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте оператор `+` для объединения переменных и строк в одну строку.

Также у вас избыточная функция `namadd`. Сложение можно провести прямо в выводе.

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a=73,b=62;
    System.out.println("a + b = " + a + " + " + b + " = " + (a + b));
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Вместо запятых надо "+":

```
System.out.print("a + b = %d + %d = %d"+a+b+namadd(a,b));
```

Итог:

> a + b = %d + %d = %d7362135